# Diesel engine on LPG

Tags: engine-theory, diesel, lpg

I have seen LPG powered petrol cars which can run on both the fuels. But I have not seen any Diesel engine car running on LPG. Is it possible to run a diesel engine on LPG?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but not very easily or effectively. To convert to 100% lpg means reducing the compression ratio and providing a spark. The lower compression ratio takes away diesel as a fuel and providing a spark means introducing a spark plug into the head - with machining issues : space, depth etc.

Using lpg with diesel - called fumigation can improve deisel economy but the cost of the lpg equipment is also a factor.

As the diesel engines are designed with a lower rev range compared to petrol engines, it seems obvious why it is not popular....

More info here : http://www.go-lpg.co.uk/diesel.html

Comment: But what could this experiment accomplish in terms of MPG economy? The high compression ratio of diesel itself is very efficient. But your suggestion of fumigation sounds promising. Do you believe this method could benefit transportation trucks in achieving higher MPG?